# Modifying Element with jQuery using Event

Tags: jquery, events, dom

I have a table set up such that each row has a checkbox as the first item in the row (think Gmail's inbox). The `<tr>` of that row has a hover and click event handler bound to it.

What I want to happen is, when the user clicks on the checkbox, the checkbox becomes checked and that's all. When the user clicks anywhere else in the row, it should do something else. I am trying to achieve this by looking at the `event.target` of the event being passed and seeing if that's a checkbox or not. However, with my current implementation, when the user clicks on the checkbox, nothing happens and when they click anywhere else in the row, it behaves how I expect.

What am I doing wrong with regards to the checkbox?

Here is my code:

```
$('.navTable > tbody > tr').hover(function() {

if (!$(this).children('td').hasClass('spacer') && !$(this).children('th').length > 0)
    $(this).css({background : "#EFEFEF", border : "1px solid #CCC"});
},function() {
    $(this).css({background : "", border : ""});
}).click(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if(e.target.attributes[0].nodeValue == "checkbox") {
        // Check the checkbox
        $("#"+e.target.id).attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
    return false;
});
```

Thank you for any help you might provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you make separate click handlers for the checkbox and elsewhere in the row:

```
$('.navTable > tbody > tr input').click(function(e) {
    // do whatever you want here
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("click checkbox");
})

$('.navTable tr').click(function(e) {
    // click in a row, that's not in the checkbox
    alert("click row");
})
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KEu3a/.

Comment: Ah, this seems like a much better solution. I am wondering, though, why my approach doesn't work? EDIT: Actually, now that I've tried it, your method does not seem to work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Works for me in my jsFiddle.  I made a few edits so make sure you try the latest version.  If it isn't working for you, then please  post both the code and HTML you tried it with in your question.  This works in concept if you get the implementation right.  You can see it in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.navTable tr').hover(function() { 
    if (!$(this).children('td').hasClass('spacer') && !$(this).children('th').length > 0) 
    $(this).css({background : "#EFEFEF", border : "1px solid #CCC"}); 
    },function() { 
            $(this).css({background : "", border : ""}); 
    }).closest('table')
        .delegate(':checkbox', 'change',function() { 
            var $checkbox = $(this),
            $td = $checkbox.closest('td'),
            $tr = $td.closest('tr');

        //If its not checked do something else.
        if($checkbox.not(':checked')) { 
      // Do something else 
    } 
    return false; 
});
```